# How to check if gprs is active on SIM800L for Arduino?

Tags: iot, aws-iot

I am working on a project,
Using esp32 and gsm800l, is there any chance of signal loss or gprs loss once after initiating at commands and gprs.

If yes then how we will check gprs is connected or not in a optimized way.

We are executing the at command after ever 5 minutes which again increases the latency of the iot device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AT+CSQ` to monitor the signal strength of your device in software.
Something like this:

```
Serial2.write("AT+CSQ=?\r");
signal_strength = Serial2.read();
//some logic to read the value and compare it against a threshold
```

Comment: Try to understand my question buddy, sometimes even the signal strength is good we loose 2g gprs connection which again needs to be re-initiated. My question is how will I check the for active 2g gprs connection or not.

Comment: "AT+CGATT?\r" will return the state of the GPRS attachment. If returns 1 then attached, and if 0 then detached.